# AS3 making a default array work: function example(human:Array = ["heart","skull"])?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3

So the only thing that seems to work is:

```
function example(human:Array = null)
{
  if (human == null)
  human = ["heart","skull"]
}
```

Why is it I can do:

```
function example(human:String = "Heart"){}
function example(human:Number = 1){}
```

but

```
function example(human:Array = ["Heart","Chest"])
```

gives me:

```
 Scene 1, Layer 'Layer 1', Frame 1, Line 1  1047: Parameter initializer unknown or is not a compile-time constant.
```

Is the if statement the only work around to making a default array parameter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

ActionScript only allows compile-time constants (string, number, int, null) as default parameters. Arrays and object instances cannot be constants because they are references. Hence, you cannot use them as default parameters.