# Is there any way to assign default value to an array passed as parameter in function, in ActionScript?

Tags: arrays, actionscript-3, flash

protected function testMethod(event:FlexEvent, args : Array = [] ):void {
...
            }

this doesn't work , throws error : 1047: Parameter initializer unknown or is not a compile-time constant.

So is there any way to assign default value to an array passed as parameter in function, in ActionScript?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31307707/as3-making-a-default-array-work-function-examplehumanarray-heart-skull

Comment: Thanks @3vilguy, however I tried searching stackoverflow and it didn't show up relevant result hence dared to post question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no built-in feature for this usecase but you could work around it pretty easily like this:

```
protected function testMethod(event:FlexEvent, args:Array):void{
    if(args == null || args.length == 0){
       args = ["these", "are", "my", "default", "values", 3, 5, false];

    }
    ....
}
```

Alternatively, you could take a look at the [... (rest) Parameter](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_ProgrammingAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9b90204-7f56.html) (bottom of the page)

Answer (score 0):

Assigning a constant defined elsewhere to the argument as default will solve the issue. ;)

Comment: I'm not sure about it... What if you push something to this array?